# Compute reaction time required?

Tags: calculus

Say I have two options:

1. I get a notification every 1/64 of a second.
2. I get a notification every 1/128 of a second.

The difference in milliseconds between notifications for the options can be computed as $1000/64 - 1000/128 = 7.8125$. This result might not be very related, but here is my question:

How can I compute the reaction time(measured in milliseconds) required to notice a difference between the two options?

Comment: Why is this a calculus question?

Comment: @FShrike What else would you think? :)

Comment: Well I mean, you can notice the difference if you had a reaction time less than $7.8125$... I'm not really sure what the main point of the question is! Calculus is about limits and derivatives and analysis and so on - no relevance here that I can see